# case expression and when statement true value is created for the grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle12c

I have the below table: I need to add a column that captured the request process.

Two option. "Manual" or "Automated"

I will capture the "Manual" else is "Automated"

I have the below sql that captured "Manual" but it only writes to the row where all conditions are true. I need this value for all the rows in a `grouping`

Criteria is in `case expression` below in `sql`

```
    NO  ACTION_DT             REQUEST_TYPE  STATUS_CD ACTION_USER REQUEST_START_DT      REQUEST_END_DT        REQUEST RNK_GRP_REQUEST
    803 5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM  CREATE        APPROVED  CH          5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM  5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM  1         1
    803 1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM  UPDATE        APPROVED  TNO         1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM  1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM  2         1
    803 4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM  UPDATE        APPROVED  TINO        4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM  4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM  3         1
    803 8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM   UPDATE        PENDING   CAD7383     8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM   8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM   4         1
    803 8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM   UPDATE        APPROVED  TINO        8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM   8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM   4         2
    803 11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM UPDATE        NEW       TLN         11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM 11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM 5         1
    803 11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM UPDATE        APPROVED  TLN         11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM 11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM 5         2
    803 7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  UPDATE        NEW       WJH         7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  6         1
    803 7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  UPDATE        PENDING   WJH         7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  6         2
    803 7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM  UPDATE        NEW       WJH         7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  7         1
    803 7/16/2019 2:31:20 PM  UPDATE        PENDING   DXL         7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  7         2
    803 7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  UPDATE        APPROVED  DXL         7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  7         3
```

Expected Results: (new column far right) (capturing manual only for now)

```
    NO  ACTION_DT             REQUEST_TYPE  STATUS_CD ACTION_USER REQUEST_START_DT      REQUEST_END_DT        REQUEST RNK_GRP_REQUEST  REQUEST
    803 5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM  CREATE        APPROVED  CH          5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM  5/6/2008 11:07:28 PM  1         1
    803 1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM  UPDATE        APPROVED  TNO         1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM  1/3/2013 10:02:04 AM  2         1
    803 4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM  UPDATE        APPROVED  TINO        4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM  4/21/2015 2:20:27 PM  3         1
    803 8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM   UPDATE        PENDING   CAD7383     8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM   8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM   4         1
    803 8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM   UPDATE        APPROVED  TINO        8/1/2017 3:25:01 PM   8/2/2017 9:34:16 AM   4         2
    803 11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM UPDATE        NEW       TLN         11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM 11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM 5         1
    803 11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM UPDATE        APPROVED  TLN         11/13/2018 4:12:36 PM 11/15/2018 9:02:07 AM 5         2
    803 7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  UPDATE        NEW       WJH         7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  6         1
    803 7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  UPDATE        PENDING   WJH         7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  7/15/2019 9:07:32 AM  6         2
    803 7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM  UPDATE        NEW       WJH         7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  7         1              MANUAL        
    803 7/16/2019 2:31:20 PM  UPDATE        PENDING   DXL         7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  7         2              MANUAL
    803 7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  UPDATE        APPROVED  DXL         7/16/2019 9:23:43 AM  7/16/2019 2:35:47 PM  7         3              MANUAL
```

Current SQL (below)...(focus on last three rows)

How can I get value "manual" for request #7?

```
request
Manual
(null) --should be Manual
(null) --should be Manual
```

SQL:

```
select *
,CASE
WHEN FIRST_VALUE(STATUS_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY NO,REQUEST ORDER BY ACTION_DT)IN ('NEW') 
 AND COUNT(REQUEST) OVER (PARTITION BY NO,REQUEST ORDER BY REQUEST) > 1 
 AND LEAD(ACTION_USER) OVER (PARTITION BY NO,REQUEST ORDER BY ACTION_DT) <> ACTION_USER
THEN 'MANUAL' --OVER (PARTITION BY NO,REQUEST ORDER BY ACTION_DT)
ELSE NULL
END REQUEST_PROCESS 

from A
```

Comment: Thanks John.  Can you include which version of the database you are using?  The set of available solutions to this differ, depending on the database version.

Comment: @alexgibbs db version 12C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using lead to compare with the next user, you could count how many different users are in the partition/group:

```
select a.*,
  CASE
    WHEN FIRST_VALUE(STATUS_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY NO, REQUEST ORDER BY ACTION_DT) = 'NEW'
      AND COUNT(REQUEST) OVER (PARTITION BY NO, REQUEST) > 1 
      AND COUNT(DISTINCT ACTION_USER) OVER (PARTITION BY NO, REQUEST) > 1
    THEN 'MANUAL'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS REQUEST_PROCESS 
from A;

        NO ACTION_DT           REQUES STATUS_C ACTION_ REQUEST_START_DT    REQUEST_END_DT         REQUEST RNK_GRP_REQUEST REQUES
---------- ------------------- ------ -------- ------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- --------------- ------
       803 2008-05-06 23:07:28 CREATE APPROVED CH      2008-05-06 23:07:28 2008-05-06 23:07:28          1               1       
       803 2013-01-03 10:02:04 UPDATE APPROVED TNO     2013-01-03 10:02:04 2013-01-03 10:02:04          2               1       
       803 2015-04-21 14:20:27 UPDATE APPROVED TINO    2015-04-21 14:20:27 2015-04-21 14:20:27          3               1       
       803 2017-08-01 15:25:01 UPDATE PENDING  CAD7383 2017-08-01 15:25:01 2017-08-02 09:34:16          4               1       
       803 2017-08-02 09:34:16 UPDATE APPROVED TINO    2017-08-01 15:25:01 2017-08-02 09:34:16          4               2       
       803 2018-11-13 16:12:36 UPDATE NEW      TLN     2018-11-13 16:12:36 2018-11-15 09:02:07          5               1       
       803 2018-11-15 09:02:07 UPDATE APPROVED TLN     2018-11-13 16:12:36 2018-11-15 09:02:07          5               2       
       803 2019-07-15 09:07:32 UPDATE NEW      WJH     2019-07-15 09:07:32 2019-07-15 09:07:32          6               1       
       803 2019-07-15 09:07:32 UPDATE PENDING  WJH     2019-07-15 09:07:32 2019-07-15 09:07:32          6               2       
       803 2019-07-16 09:23:43 UPDATE NEW      WJH     2019-07-16 09:23:43 2019-07-16 14:35:47          7               1 MANUAL
       803 2019-07-16 14:31:20 UPDATE PENDING  DXL     2019-07-16 09:23:43 2019-07-16 14:35:47          7               2 MANUAL
       803 2019-07-16 14:35:47 UPDATE APPROVED DXL     2019-07-16 09:23:43 2019-07-16 14:35:47          7               3 MANUAL

12 rows selected.
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=817920bcb0a6385a7c119df6aed3aa7f)

I'm not sure you even need the `COUNT_REQUEST)` check, as that has to be more than one if the user count is.